# how to use constructor and update constructor values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to access the constructor variable and use them throughout my code at some part of my code I need to update it too

I am trying to update react-native Picker value with this code

This is how I use the constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Locations = _.uniq(_.map(this.props.Bikes, 'location'));
    this.selectedLocationValue = this.Locations[0];
  }
```

This is where I update it:

```js
<Picker
  mode='dropdown'
  selectedValue={this.selectedLocationValue}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => { this.selectedLocationValue = itemValue; }}
>
```

I cant change It to other values this is the problem that I am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your constructor add a default value and assign that default value as the first value of Locations

then in your state assign the value of selectedLocationValue as the default value
like:

```js
constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.Locations = _.uniq(_.map(this.props.Bikes, 'location'));
     this.defaultValue = this.Locations[0];
  }

  state = {
     selectedLocationValue: this.defaultValue
  }
  
  <Picker
    mode='dropdown'
    selectedValue={this.state.selectedLocationValue}
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => { this.setState({ selectedLocationValue: itemValue }); }}
  >
```

Comment: this will show a default value and we can change this value to the item in the Picker

Answer (score 1):

```html
<Picker
  mode='dropdown'
  selectedValue={this.state.selectedLocationValue}
  onValueChange={itemValue => this.setState({selectedLocationValue: itemValue}) }
>
```

Because `selectedLocationValue` is a state of the current component, you should put it into state of the component.

Comment: and in state  i cant  keep `selectedLocationValue = this.Location[0]`
But I need that value as the current selectedvalue

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `this` from the html markup.

```
<Picker mode='dropdown'
 selectedValue={selectedLocationValue}
 onValueChange={(itemValue) => { selectedLocationValue = itemValue; }}>
```

and share the results.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor do this

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.setState({
       selectedLocationValue: _.uniq(_.map(this.props.Bikes, 'location'))[0]
   });
}
```

Then in your Picker Component do this

```
<Picker
  mode='dropdown'
  selectedValue={this.state.selectedLocationValue}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => { 
     this.setState({ selectedLocationValue: itemValue }); 
  }}
>
```

The benefit of setting this using state, is that everytime your value of Picker updated it will cause a re render and this will update your UI as well.

You could also have this done this by using `this.selectedLocations` as well. But React recommends anything that is UI dependent as in a value that needs to change on your UI should be kept in state. So that everytime a state changes React will know and it can update your View accordingly.